# Jade mixin default parameters

Tags: pug

I have a following mixin in Jade:

```
mixin indicator(slide_to, active)
  - active = active || '' // this is an ugly method to create a default value
  li(class=active, data-target='#' + CAROUSEL_ID, data-slide-to=slide_to)
```

and I call it like this:

```
+indicator(1) 
+indicator(2, 'active')
```

I want the parameter `active` to have a default value of `''`. I have found the ugly workaround as is shown in my codesample. Is there a better way to do this in Jade?

Comment: As far as I know: No.

Comment: But if you want the class to be empty why not just leave it like it is? If you set `class=active` while active isn't defined there won't be any class attribute at all.

Comment: No, there would be class=undefined if active is not set

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This example:

```
mixin test(slide_to, active)
    li(class=active, data-slide-to=slide_to)

+test('a')
+test('a', 'b')
```

Compiles into this HTML for me:

```
<li data-slide-to="a"></li>
<li data-slide-to="a" class="b"></li>
```

I'm using Jade 0.35.0.

Jade doesn't add falsy values. You can read this in the [Jade reference](http://jade-lang.com/reference/attributes#booleanattribs) in the subchapter Boolean Attributes.

Answer (score 2):

The answer needs to be updated since it is obviously possible today.

```
mixin test(slide_to= 'a', active='')
  li(class=active, data-slide-to=slide_to)

+test()
+test('b')
+test('c', 'active')
```

Compiles into this HTML for me:

```
<li class="" data-slide-to="a"></li>
<li class="" data-slide-to="b"></li>
<li class="active" data-slide-to="c"></li>
```